# Are there any components compatible with EV3 that are more powerful and durable?

Tags: ev3, 3rd-party

Are there components compatible with EV3 like motors, sensors, brackets, other details that I can easily connect to an existing EV3 main block and build something to do real-life tasks? Like transporting weights on the route, cocktail maker that could handle glass bottles, home cleaner that can put objects in the order.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Tetrix](http://www.legoeducation.us/eng/categories/products/high-school/tetrix) or [Matrix](http://matrixrobotics.com/products/). Theese building systems have more porefull motors than NXT ones. Metal blocks allow you to create strong robots. Tetrix and Matrix robots can be controlled by NXT/EV3.